# Idiomatic way to represent nullary data constructor

Tags: common-lisp

In Haskell, if I wanted something like a binary tree I would use an algebraic data type.

```
data BinTree a b = EmptyBinTree | BinTree a (Maybe b) (BinTree a) (BinTree a)
```

In Common Lisp, I might represent an empty tree as a dedicated self-evaluating symbol like `:empty-bin-tree` or a general purpose one like `nil`. I would represent the general case of a binary tree as

```
(defun make-bin-tree
    (key-value
     &optional (left-child :empty-bin-tree)
     &optional (right-child :empty-bin-tree))
  "(list key value?) left-child? right-child? -> bin-tree"
  (list key-value left-child right-child))
```

With nothing explicit corresponding to the `BinTree` constructor in the Haskell code.

Is there an idiomatic or conventional way to represent the equivalent of a nullary data constructor as a self-evaluating symbol in the current package instead of re-purposing a keyword?

Comment: I don't know if it's idiomatic, but you can certainly do it.  It would just be `(defconstant foo 'foo)`.

Comment: Note that the lambda list in your definition is incorrect (see the [specification](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_da.htm)): it should be `(key-value &optional (leftChild :empty-bin-tree) (rightChild :empty-bin-tree))`. Note, moreover, that it is not idiomatic to use camelCase in Common Lisp, much more common are variable names like `left-child` and `right-child`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can roll your own, as detailed in the other answer. It seems like you want to use ML-style algebraic data types in Common Lisp. It turns out you can: this amazing library by tarballs_are_good: https://github.com/stylewarning/cl-algebraic-data-type implements them.

Unfortunately, this library does not support parametric recursive types, because it is hard to retrofit these onto a dynamic language via macroology alone. If this abstraction is non-negotiable to you, you may want to look at a Lisp like [Shen](http://www.shenlanguage.org/) that supports it from the ground up.

Edit: [trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia) is now the de-facto standard for pattern matching libraries. It is compatible with optima but under more active development, I believe.

Comment: The library itself though does seem pretty interesting. It's a few macros wrapping `defstruct` and a constructor-to-arity hash table `*constructors*`. Are ADTs defined using this package designed to be globally available or local to the current package?

Comment: @Gregory Nisbet, I believe you can export your ADTs the same way you would export your structs.

Comment: @Riley -- the repository for `cl-algebraic-data-type` has moved, so I updated the link. The link to `adt-optima-bridge` also seems to be broken; maybe you could update that or edit it out.

Comment: Done! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

It's easy enough to make a symbol self-evaluating.  You can just use defconstant.  Then you can create a tree function like you're suggesting where the left and right subtrees are optional, and default to the empty tree:

```
(defconstant empty-tree 'empty-tree)

(defun tree (element &optional
                       (left empty-tree)
                       (right empty-tree))
  (list element left right))
```

```
CL-USER> (tree 3)
(3 EMPTY-TREE EMPTY-TREE)

CL-USER> (tree 3 (tree 4))
(3 (4 EMPTY-TREE EMPTY-TREE) EMPTY-TREE)

CL-USER> (tree 3 (tree 4) (tree 5))
(3 (4 EMPTY-TREE EMPTY-TREE) (5 EMPTY-TREE EMPTY-TREE))
```

That said, I don't know whether this would be considered particularly idiomatic.  You now have a way to check for empty trees, but no definite way to check for non-empty trees.  That is, how would you know whether it's a tree, or just some list?

I think that it would be more typical to use either completely implicit typing, or to use completely explicit typing.  Implicit typing would say something like:

A binary tree is either:

- a list of the form (element left-subtree right-subtree)
- the empty tree, nil.

That's easy enough to implement:

```
(defun tree-element (tree)
  (first tree))

(defun tree-left (tree)
  (second tree))

(defun tree-right (tree)
  (third tree))

(defun treep (object)
  (and (listp object)
       (or (= 3 (length object))  ; doesn't check subtrees, though
           (null object))))
```

Note that the **treep** predicate doesn't check subtrees, though.  That's kind of like **listp**, which will check whether something is **nil** or a **cons**, but doesn't go farther down.  It's also a matter of taste whether the length of a tree really needs to be three or not.  After all, you can still do, e.g.,  **(tree-right '(1 (2)))** and get **nil** back.

You could also do something a bit more explicit, with type information actually embedded into the objects, so that you could check arguments, etc.  I think that's a less common approach, but you can get typed objects using CLOS or structures.  Structures will, by default, give you a lot of the same accessors, too.  An approach with structures might look like this (be sure to read the comments in the code):

```
(defstruct (binary-tree
             ;; By default, DEFSTRUCT would define a BINARY-TREE-P
             ;; predicate that would be true only of the structure
             ;; objects.  The structure objects are just the internal
             ;; nodes; NIL is the leaf, so instead we define
             ;; INTERNAL-BINARY-TREE-P, and define BINARY-TREE-P
             ;; later.
             (:predicate internal-binary-tree-p))
  element   ; defines binary-tree-element
  left      ;    ''   binary-tree-left
  right)    ;    ''   binary-tree-right

(defun binary-tree-p (object)
  (or (null object)
      (internal-binary-tree-p object)))
```

Or, you could a type hierarchy with structures, too.  The problem with type hierarchies, of course, is that you have no way to lock them.  E.g., you could define a binary-tree class with no slots, and then subclasses empty-binary-tree and internal-binary-tree, but if someone comes along and defines another subclass, it's a binary-tree, too, even though you wanted algebraic behavior.

Common Lisp is a flexible enough language that you can develop algebraic datatypes if you want, and forgiving enough that you can enforce as little or as much as you want.  I think the most common approach, and certainly the easiest earlier on, would be to simply treat your data that way. The compiler won't enforce that you don't pass a non-tree to a tree-expecting function, but you can still get most of the benefits.